# How to open the IntelliJ IDEA in Windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ  IDEA for my windows 10 successfully. But when I click to open the IntelliJ  IDEA it doesn't open and not show any single error message pop up.
Can I get an answer why is that, please?
And How to open it in Windows?

Comment: Check `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 20xx\bin` and check `idea.exe` or `idea64.exe` exist. Then click on the right one based on your windows (I think `idea64.exe` );

Comment: Okay. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows command prompt and start IDE from command line using `idea.bat` script, located in `IDE_HOME/bin` directory and examine the output to see the error message it reports if it does not start.